# How can I monitor bandwidth usage on a HSPA/UMTS WiFi hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

As our only internet access (currently traveling - no fixed address - no fixed phone line) we use a Huawei E586 personal Wifi hotspot [http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=3148&directoryId=5009&treeId=3619&tab=0], through which we connect up to 3 devices (my ultrabook, my wife's notebook, and a Kobo) to the internet - in changing configurations (eg. sometimes only my wife, sometimes only me, oftentimes 2 devices).

**We would like to monitor our overall bandwidth consumption on this HSPA/UMTS device, as we keep exceeding the (rather low) bandwidth allowance of our monthly plan!**

I checked various sources, but most monitoring tools seem to be designed for a router, where the total bandwidth is measured either at the network port, or at the port connecting the router to the cable or land line - so they are of no use to us. I looked into several tools, like Netmeter (which I installed, it said "nothing to monitor" and had nothing to change under 'options'), iTraffic (which says nothing about HSPS/UMTS in its description - will it work?), NetspeedMonitor (again, this seems to measure "network traffic", not wireless or HSPA/UMTS traffic)... Our Huawei E586 comes with a small built-in software, but this loses all data as soon as (for example) the mobile network drops out, which tends to happen too often with mediocre reception - *so I cannot record a reliable summary.*